# How do I set some attributes e,g white space = nowrap to the url extracted from content before asigning it to span textContent

Tags: javascript, jquery, less

Any logic of setting attributes to a substring in javascript.

```
if (spanArr.length != 0) {
var span = document.createElement('span');
var content = spanArr.join(" ");
var url = content.match(/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[+~%\/.\w-]*)?\??(?:[-+=&;%@.\w])#?(?:[\w]))?)/);

    span.textContent = ?;
    divContent.appendChild(span);
  }
```

How do I set some attributes e,g white space = nowrap to the url extracted from content before asigning it to span textContent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have a few concepts mixed up here.

[white-space: nowrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) is a CSS statement that, when applied to an HTML element, causes the text and any [inline level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flow_Layout) inside that element to not wrap to the next line when the edge of the element is reached. This only applies to block level elements that have a width or otherwise do not have the option to expand to accomodate the content.

CSS attributes like `white-space` can only be applied to DOM Elements, not to strings (like your `url`). The `url`, in this case, would be the text content (in fact, the `textContent`) of the `span` element. The `white-space` would be a CSS attribute of the element.

CSS attributes can be applied to DOM elements in 3 ways: through CSS declarations in a [`<style>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style) tag or external CSS file; though the HTML [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/style) attribute, or through direct manipulation in JavaScript of the related [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) property of a DOM `HTMLElement`.

Since you are working in JavaScript, you want to do the latter here. If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, the following code should get you what you want:

```
span.textContent = url;
span.style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap';
divContent.appendChild(span);
```

Note: in JavaScript the CSS properties of the `style` property are written in camelCase (with capitals in the middle of words) instead of kebab-case (with hyphens between words), because JavaScript would interpret the `-` character as an arithmetic operator if you were to use that.

Another note: the `white-space` applied to a `span` will probably not do a lot, since a `span` is not a block level element. If your goal is to make the `span`s not wrap within the `divContent` element, you should add the styling to that element instead:

```
divContent.style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap';
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have managed to resolve the issue